# Unable to insert into mysql database using php because of the query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code where i want to insert some values into a particular database. For some reason the records are not stored into the database. I have an idea that something is wrong with my mysql_query.

Possible problems which you think might cause this problem (I have checked , and they do not affect my problem):
Connection to the database is not established.
Variables do not contain values.

Here is the code:

```
 <?php 
include('includes/connect-db.php'); 

$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['firstname'])));
$surname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['surname'])));
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['username'])));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['password'])));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['email'])));
$tel = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['tel'])));
$month = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['month'])));
$day = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['day'])));
$year = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['year'])));
$address = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['address'])));
$postcode = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['postcode'])));
$city = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['city'])));
$country = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['country'])));

if(isset($_POST['submit_register'])) {


    if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($surname) && !empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email) && !empty($tel) && !empty($month) && 
    !empty($day) && !empty($year) && !empty($address) && !empty($city) && !empty($country)) {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (firstname, surname, username, password, email, tel, month, day, year, address, city, country)
    VALUES ('$firstname','$surname','$username','$password', '$email', '$tel', '$month', '$day','$year','$address','$postcode','$city','$country')");
    echo'success';
    }
    else{
    echo'failure';
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: when you run the code, does it echo success or failure?

Comment: You don't check the result of `mysql_query`. It returns `false` in case of an error, after which you can also fetch an [error message(http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). You can look up the [documentation on `mysql_query` here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Also make sure to read that big red box at the top of the page, that says you shouldn't use this function at all anymore.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **you should not be using mysql_query** since this extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, use the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension.

Regarding your code, you have forgotten to add the postcode column type in your SQL query.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (firstname, surname, username, password, email, tel, month, day, year, address, postcode, city, country)
VALUES ('$firstname','$surname','$username','$password', '$email', '$tel', '$month', '$day','$year','$address','$postcode','$city','$country')");
```

If that does not work then check if any of the variables that you are trying to store to your database are missing and if they are then give them a null value.

For example:

```
if ( isset($_POST['firstname']) ) {
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['firstname'])));
} else {
    $firstname = '';
}
```

Alternatively you can use the "[ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)":

```
$firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['firstname']))) : '';
```

Do this for all your variables and then try to run the query.

Comment: I have now added the postcode column - it still doesnt insert the record

Comment: I have edited my answer. Add an if statement for each of the variables that you are trying to store. If empty then make it equal to "". If it helped you please accept it.:)

Answer (score 0):

What i usually do in such cases, i copy my sql query statement to mysql terminal.
I try the code there to find if it runs without any issue.
If it doesn't then mysql will raise an error.
if it does then i usually use sprintf function to format the query.
Something like this:

```
if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($surname) && !empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email) && !empty($tel) && !empty($month) && 
!empty($day) && !empty($year) && !empty($address) && !empty($city) && !empty($country)) {

    $query = sprintf('INSERT INTO customers (firstname, surname, username, password, email, tel, month, day, year, address, city, country) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',$firstname,$surname,$username,$password,$email,$tel,$month,$day,$year,$address,$postcode,$city,$country);

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result){
        echo 'Success';
    }else{
        echo 'Failure';
    }
}
```

The %s is a string placeholder when using the sprintf function. there are several of them. check php docs.